# button dropdown content hiding in bootstrap accordion

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap-2

In bootstrap2.3 [accordion] the button dropdown content is hiding inside accordion even if applied [css] z-index property. this template is rendering from backbone.

https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/uploads-ap.hipchat.com/31869/595252/xt2tIhUVljz1N6R/Screen%20Shot%202014-07-25%20at%2012.32.17%20PM.png

Comment: There might be an overflow:hidden; to the wrapper of that dropdown menu.

Comment: please add your code so that it will be clarified correctly